# "Закладывать средства в бюджетЕ" или "в бюджет"?

Tags: лексика

Как правильно сказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**В бюджете**. Бюджет не силосная яма, а источник. 
Кстати, "закладывать" - тоже не всегда уместный жаргонизм. Бюждетные средства надо **резервировать**. 
А "закладывать (куда?)" можно в смету расходов или, скажем, график исполнения бюджета.

К сожалению, понимание этих вещей сейчас резко уходит в ноль.
Не в последнюю очередь - в связи с широким распространением компьютерных программ, создатели которых не всегда способны отслеживать соблюдение сложившейся терминологии.

Answer (score 0):

Если по правилам русского языка, то глагол заклыдывать требует винительного падежа: **закладывать (*куда? во что?*) в бюджет**. А вот **заложены (*где? в чём?*) в бюджете** - предложный падеж.

Comment: Боюсь, русский язык о своих требованиях не знает.
Заладывать (что?) фундамент - винительный.
Закладывать (чем?) кирпичом - творительный.
А куда - это разве что в ломбард. 
Кстати, вас не смущает, что петь можно одновременно в микрофон и в Большом театре? А как вам вопрос "Где я могу заложить вещи?" - "В соседнем доме".

Здесь на самом деле вот какая штука иммет место. Бухгалтерское значение шлагола "заложить", как уже сказал, чисто жаргонное, словарями не придусмотренное. Оно означает "предусмотреть", "зарезервировать", "учесть". Ну нету у этих глаголов значения "куда?".